# Show multiple instances of div synchronous according to number of elements in select list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, synchronous

I have a select list that gets items from the datababase where we can add other items to it from an other list or delete items in it,

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
 <label for="IX">Selected Issuing Banks</label>     
<select id="IX" name="IX" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px; height: 70px; margin: 0px 2px 0px 3px;" data-bind="options: IX, optionsText: function(item) { return item.Name +' (' + item.BICCode + ')' }, optionsValue: 'Id',value: IdIX"></select>
</div>
```

And just after the selectlist, I have a div with multiple textfields to insert into the database,
I want to show multiple numbers of this same div synchronously according to the items in the select, if the list essentially has 2 times we'll have this div shown twice, if we add another item to the list it will become 3 times and I am having trouble with making this

Answer (score 0):

The trick will be in naming elements but jquery `.each()` should get you started:

```
$("#IX option").each(function () {
    $("body").append($("#fieldsDiv").html());
});
```

I'd recommend using a [content template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) and dynamically build the new divs based on it:

```
<div class="divContainer">
</div>

<template id="fieldsDivTemplate">
    <div class="fields">
        <!-- your fields go here use {{tags}} as placeholders for id values -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    $(function () {
        let t = $("#fieldsDivTemplate").html();
        t = t.replace(/{{tags}}/g, "value from select list item goes here");

        body.append(t);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately i can't use a content template in my case, though the .each() solution worked when i used it in the initialization of the items, but when i call it on the same button that adds a new item to the list, it adds not a new div but the (n+1) , i had 2 items by default in my list, so it gave me the same DIV twice, when i added a new item the method called appended the field 3 more times.. 
plus i will have the same problem with deleting an element from the list